# Can't update my xamarin.forms 4.6 to android part of my project

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i was trying to update my xamarin.forms via nuget to 4.6.xx i'm currently using 4.2.xx. as i update the xamarin forms, it just update the shared and ios only. the android left behind with the same version (4.2.xx) of xamarin.forms. any idea? thank you.

[image]

an error during update appears. see the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Through the message in the console,

`Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils 28.0.0.1` needs `Xamarin.Android.Support.Loader` **28.0.0.1**

while

`Xamarin.forms 4.0.6.726` needs `Xamarin.Android.Support.Loader` **28.0.0.3**

So update your `Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils` to version `28.0.0.3` first and then you can update your Xamarin.forms in Android project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply Jack Hua, I never had a chance to apply your suggestion because I've manage to update Xamarin.Forms 4.6.xx to my android [See Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWamf.png). What I did is on **Android SDKs and Tools** (Platform) tab under Android 10.0.Q, I downloaded **Android SDK Platform 29** and **Source for Android 29** [See Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0Svk.png). Then in my android project properties. I set my Target Framework to Android 10.0Q [See Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ09h.png). Lastly, I go to Manage Nugets Packages again then update to Xamarin.Forms 4.6.xx. After a clean and rebuild, it runs smoothly without error [See Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DIA1.png). I think Android 10.0.Q is equal to Android.x.